React-query: isFetching vs isLoading vs isPending
function Fa({children}) {
    const {data, isFetching} = useQuery({queryKey: ['key'], queryFn: () => getFetcher('/myapi')});
    if(isFetching) return <Spin/>;
    return children   
}
function Ch() {
    const {data} = useQuery({queryKey: ['key'], queryFn: () => getFetcher('/myapi')});
    return <div>children</div>
}
export default MyComponent {
    return <Fa>
        <Ch/>
    </Fa>
}

when i use isFetching, i found out that the component is rerendering and refetching many times, why?
if i want the data is already loaded then go to children, what status should i use? isLoading / isFetching / isPending is not what i want
